# difference between 計画を立てる and 計画をする？

Tags: word-choice, words, usage

Is there any difference between 計画【けいかく】を立てる【たてる】 and  計画をする? In 
*Sou Matome N3*, the first one appears as "*to make plans*", as for the second one (being a *suru verb*), I assume that it can also be associated with *to make plans*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is almost no difference in their meanings, and the two phrases are almost always interchangeable. I said almost because I can not think of even a single counter example in a few minutes as a native speaker.

By the way, you can also use a verb, '計画する', without 'を' in a similar way. For example,

- 旅行の計画を立てる。
- 旅行の計画をする。

are similar to

- 旅行を計画する。

The first two sentences are not completely the same as the last one. The last sentence sounds to stress more that the decision is made to go to a trip compared to the first two, which sounds to have more stress on deciding on the details during the trip.